# Show convergence of this infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I am looking for a way to show that his infinite product converges, but I am not sure how to go about it. Any hint would be great.

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^{x}$$

Comment: Do you know that $\sum_j \log(1+1/j)-1/j$ converges ? Because it is $=\sum_j1/j+ O(1/j^2)-1/j$. Here it is the same after taking the $\log$

Comment: Hint: take natural logarithm of both sides (assuming $|x|<1$ and use series expansion of $\ln$ to obtain an expression that’s easier to see its convergence (after noting that the first term of both expressions cancel out).

Comment: The product gives $\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: @reuns No I dont :/ How does the big O notation appear here in the convergence term?

Comment: I'm just using that $\log(1+t)=t+O(t^2)$ (as $t\to 0$) and that $\sum_j O( 1/j^2)$ converges. After taking the $\log$ of your product this is all you need.